# Erro ao adcionar imagem a uma URI - "cannot find symbol class fromFile"

Tags: android-studio, uri

Galera, não consigo encontrar o motivo pelo qual o Android Studio não reconhece o método `Uri.fromFile()`. Pesquisei em vários lugares mas nada. Meu código está assim:

```
foto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent irParaCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            caminhoArquivo = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            File arquivo = new File(caminhoArquivo);

            Uri localFoto = new Uri.fromFile(arquivo);
            irParaCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, localFoto);

            startActivityForResult(irParaCamera, 123);
        }
    });
```

O mais estranho é que o Android Studio chega a sugerir que eu utilize este método, mas quando uso ele não o reconhece. Segue os imports:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.File;
```

Estou fazendo algo errado? 
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o erro galera. No trecho:

```
Uri localFoto = new Uri.fromFile(arquivo);
```

Não há o "new". Bastou tirá-lo que funcionou.

Abraços